# How do I get all solutions from this system?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am new to linear algebra and I am trying to solve a system of three equations with five unknowns. The system I have is the following:

```
x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 = 1
-x1 + x2 + x3 - 2x4 - 2x5 = 1
2x1 + 2x2 - x3 - x4 + x5 = 1
```

So what I did was set up the augmented matrix like this:

```
    1  1  1  1  1  1
   -1  1  1 -2 -2  1
    2  2 -1 -1  1  1
```

Then I try to obtain an identity matrix on the left side and end up with the following:

```
    1  0  0  3/2  3/2  0
    0  1  0 -3/2 -5/6  2/3
    0  0  1  1    1/3  1/3
```

So I think the answer is x1 = 0, x2 = 2/3 and x3 = 1/3

But when I look in my answer sheet it reads:

(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5) = (0, 2/3, 1/3, 0, 0) + s(−3/2, 3/2, −1, 1, 0) + t(−3/2, 5/6, −1/3, 0, 1)

I have no idea how to interpret this. My x1,x2,x3 seems to match the first three in the first five-tuple but what are the other two five-tuples? Can someone explain what I am missing here? I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Hey yo, close this question here and ask on http://math.stackexchange.com — if you have a *code*-related question, feel free to ask it here.

Answer (score 0):

A system of equations can be represented in matrix form as

```
Ax = b
```

where `A` is the matrix of coefficients, `x` is the column vector `(x1, ..., xn)` and `b` is the column vector with as many entries as equations are.

When `b` is not `0` we say that the system is *not homogeneous*. The associated *homogeneous* system is

```
Ax = 0
```

where the `0` on the right is again a column vector.

When you have a non-homogeneous system, like in this case, the general solution has the form

```
P + G
```

where `P` is any particular solution and `G` is the generic solution of the homogeneous system.

In your case the vector

```
P = (0, 2/3, 1/3, 0, 0)
```

satisfies all the equations and is therefore a valid particular solution.

The other two vectors `(−3/2, 3/2, −1, 1, 0)` and `(−3/2, 5/6, −1/3, 0, 1)` satisfy the homogeneous equations (take a moment to check this). And since there are `3` (independent) equations with `5` unknowns (`x1`..`x5`), the space of homogenous solutions can be generated by these two vectors (again because they are independent).

So, to describe the space of all homogeneous solutions you need two scalar variables `s` and `t`. In other words

```
 G = s(−3/2, 3/2, −1, 1, 0) + t(−3/2, 5/6, −1/3, 0, 1)
```

will generate all homogeneous solutions as `s` and `t` take all posible real values.